# Passing thread to threaded object

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4, qthread

Quick question on the use of `QThread` in PyQt4 and Python 2.7.  I am creating a process inherited from `QObject`, and assigning this to a `Qthread` I have created in a separate class (also inherited from `QObject`).

Is it safe to pass the `QThread` object to the process object, so that I can call `thread.msleep(mseconds)` from within the process itself?

I want to be able to make the thread wait or sleep, but I have read that time.sleep(seconds) is dodgy when used with PyQt multi-threading.

I did try to send a signal from the process object to a slot in the main thread (attached to `thread.msleep(mseconds)` for that process object), but I found that this failed to work; the process object continued executing until complete, with the slot only being executed after this time.  Even after adjusting priorities, this continued to happen.  This is unacceptable since I want the process loop to run continuously.

Any other recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pyqtSignals not emitted in QThread woker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995716/pyqtsignals-not-emitted-in-qthread-woker)

Comment: Thanks, the use of QtGui.Qpplication.processEvents() will certainly be useful for other things, but for some reason it doesn't work in my case, even if the statement immediately follows an emitted signal that calls msleep().  My main concern relates to a process controlling its own thread, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to alter my code to achieve the functionality that I required in my question: namely the ability to make a thread wait or sleep for a specified amount of time.

Firstly, my research seems to show that one of the main reasons subclassing `QThread` became ill-advised in Qt was that a thread should not be able to manage itself.  Though there is no official documentation on my question, I can only surmise that passing the thread object to the process object running on it would also be ill-advised, because the thread would again be able to control itself directly.

The solution I have found is to dispense with `msleep()` altogether.  Qt documentation on QThread recommends that `sleep()` and `wait()` functions are avoided because they do not fit well with the event driven nature of Qt.  They recommend that `QTimer()` is used to call a function via a signal after it times out, in place of `msleep()`.  By default `QTimer()` is used to send a repeating signal every time interval, but can also send a signal once using `QTimer.singleShot()`.  It is also stated in the documentation that it is safe to call `QSleep()` from within a thread.

I only use a repeating `QTimer` to call a single slot `foo()` multiple times, but to add a delay within `foo()`, `QTimer.singleShot()` could be used to call a second function `moo()` after a set number of milliseconds.

EDIT: I have decided to include my threading code, which subclasses QObject and QThread to perform a task on a thread in a continual loop every given time interval.  It is, as far as I can tell, fully functional, though could do with a little work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

# Class to be assigned to a thread.  
# This should be subclassed to provide new functionality.
class GenericLoop(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GenericLoop, self).__init__()

    # We use this signal to tell the main thread 
    # when this thread is finished.
    finished_Sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    # Default timeout is 0, i.e. do work on thread after 
    # other events have been dealt with
    __timeout = 0
    __processTimer = None
    __args = None
    __kwargs = None

    # We use this function to set the arguments used by run(),
    # if we want to change them mid-execution
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(tuple, dict)
    def changeArgs(self, args, kwargs):
        self.__args = args
        self.__kwargs = kwargs

    # We can change the timeout used to make the thread run 
    # at given intervals.  Note that the timing is not exact, 
    # since this is impossible with a real time operating system
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setTimeout(self, mseconds): 
        self.__timeout = int(mseconds)

    # Call either a singleShot QTimer (one execution), 
    # or a normal QTimer (repeated), to start the loop
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool, tuple, dict)
    def startTimer(self, singleShot, args, kwargs):
        self.__processTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        # We can't pass args and kwargs directly because QTimer.timeout 
        # emits a signal with allowing no contained variables
        # so we copy args and kwargs to local variables instead
        self.changeArgs(args, kwargs)
        if singleShot:
            self.__processTimer.singleShot(self.__timeout, self.callRun)
        else:
            self.__processTimer.timeout.connect(self.callRun)
            self.__processTimer.start(self.__timeout)

    # Call finish from within subclass using self.finish(), or 
    # from another thread using signals.  finish() will stop the 
    # QTimer causing execution of the loop.  The loop can be started again
    # by calling startTimer() or stopTimer() from another thread
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def stopTimer(self):
        if self.__processTimer.isActive():
            self.__processTimer.stop()
        else:
            print "ERROR: stopTimer() has been called but no timer is running!"

    # We call this to delete the thread.
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def deleteThread(self):
        self.finished_Sig.emit()

    # This calls run(), in order to enable the passing of 
    # command line arguments to the loop
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def callRun(self):
        self.run(self.__args, self.__kwargs)

    # run() can be called directly from another thread if required
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(tuple, dict)
    def run(self, args, kwargs):
        print "ERROR: run() has not been defined!  Stopping thread..."
        self.stopTimer()

# Class for creating threads
class GenericThread(QtCore.QObject):

    # Private variables include the thread.  
    __sendArguments_Sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple, dict)
    __startTimer_Sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, tuple, dict)
    __setTimeout_Sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    __obj = None
    __finished_Sig = None
    __thread = QtCore.QThread()

    # Object to be threaded must be specified when 
    # creating a GenericThread object
    def __init__(self, obj): 
        super(GenericThread, self).__init__()
        self.__obj = obj
        self.moreInit()

    # Set up object on thread
    def moreInit(self):
        self.__thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.__obj.moveToThread(self.__thread)

        # Allows thread to delete itself when done
        self.__obj.finished_Sig.connect(self.__thread.deleteLater)

        self.__sendArguments_Sig.connect(self.__obj.changeArgs)
        self.__startTimer_Sig.connect(self.__obj.startTimer)
        self.__setTimeout_Sig.connect(self.__obj.setTimeout)
        self.__thread.start()

    # Sets the QTimer timeout and does some checking 
    # to make sure that types are as they should be
    def setTimeout(self, mseconds):
        if mseconds >= 0 and type(mseconds) is type(int()):
            self.__setTimeout_Sig.emit(mseconds)
        elif mseconds < 0 and type(mseconds) is type(int()):
            print "Error: timeout of below 0 ms specified."
        else:
            print "Error: timeout period is specified with a type other than int."

    # Starts a function in the thread via signals, and can pass 
    # it arguments if required. Function executes until QTimer is stopped
    def startLoop(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.__thread == None):
            print "ERROR: Thread has been deleted!"
        else:
            self.__startTimer_Sig.emit(False, args, kwargs)

    # Starts a function in the thread via signals, once
    def startOnce(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.__thread == None):
            print "ERROR: Thread has been deleted!"
        else:
            self.__startTimer_Sig.emit(True, args, kwargs)

# Calls a very simple GUI just to show that the program is responsive
class GUIBox(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GUIBox, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.resize(250, 150)

        self.setWindowTitle('Threading!')
        self.show()

# Subclass GenericLoop to reimplement run and such.
class SubClassedLoop(GenericLoop):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClassedLoop, self).__init__()

    __i = 0

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(tuple, dict)
    def run(self, args, kwargs):
        if self.__i>=50:
            self.stopTimer()
            return
        print self.__i, args
        self.__i += 1

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

ex = GUIBox()

# Create 3 worker objects to do the actual calculation
worker1 = SubClassedLoop()
worker2 = SubClassedLoop()
worker3 = SubClassedLoop()

# Create 3 thread managing objects to do the thread control
thread1 = GenericThread(worker1)
thread2 = GenericThread(worker2)
thread3 = GenericThread(worker3)

# Set the threads to execute as soon as there is no work to do
thread1.setTimeout(125)
thread2.setTimeout(125)
thread3.setTimeout(125)

# Start threads
thread1.startLoop(1)
thread2.startLoop(2)
thread3.startLoop(3)

# Quit the program when the GUI window is closed
sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```